# python2.7 cannot be opened because of a problem

Tags: crash, python, macos

Running into an odd issue when my system starts up:
[image: python failure]

I have not been able to track the point of failure down yet. I assume that it is some application that is attempting to start at system startup, but I have not yet been able to isolate the application or daemon.  The actual problem report seems to be quite unhelpful in this case:

```
Process:               python2.7 [6982]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/python2.7
Identifier:            python2.7
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [6980]
Responsible:           python2.7 [6982]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-09-18 16:22:28.150 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A282b)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        032A40CC-C2C4-1235-F611-B0961DE616DB


Time Awake Since Boot: 5100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/*/python
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
    0x7fff67746000 -     0x7fff6777cf5f  dyld (360.14) <DF977301-4A63-32ED-9939-1EE3122D18D4> /usr/lib/dyld
```

I thought that perhaps it was an issue with `Homebrew`'s python installation, but after removing and re-adding it, this does not appear to be the case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does /usr/bin/python do?

Comment: @Mark `/usr/bin/python --version`: `Python 2.7.10`

Comment: What's the output of `which python`?

Comment: @Kellen `/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I don't use OSX, but on other Unixes I'd use `starce/truss` to see what's going on. I believe the equivalent on OSX is `dtruss` - so from the OSX shell run `dtruss python` and you may get a hint as to your problem.

Comment: Got the same problem today - any ideas what it was? I literally cant do anything right now...

Answer (score 1):

Was fighting with this issue today, after I upgraded python using brew, the annoying pop up wouldn't let me work on my Mac! The only difference is that it was shouting for python3.4. After couple hours of digging I just decided to:

- remove all python3 whatsoever, the one installed by brew and the one installed manually from dmg.
- search for all remaining symlinks to python I've had on my development projects folder. After deactivating all the venv's and removing the symlinks the pop up was gone.

Then I found this post of [jeremycade](http://www.jeremycade.com/python/osx/homebrew/2015/03/02/fixing-virtualenv-after-a-python-upgrade/) which explains the less aggressive approach.